# Why the proof isn't complete?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm going through some complex analysis exercises and found one with which I have some problems:

*For all real $y$,
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$
This problem requests two proofs:*

*(a) First, use the Cauchy Integral theorem to relate the two integrals.*

*(b) Second, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, show that $\alpha \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+\alpha)^2}dx$ is a holomorphic function of $\alpha$. Obtain the equality of the above integrals from the Identity Theorem for holomorphic functions.*

So, my logic is the following: for any real $y$ let's consider the integral
$$\int\limits_C e^{-z^2} dz,$$
where $C$ is a rectangular contour with vertices at $\pm R$ and $\pm R + iy$. According to the Cauchy Integral theorem, this integral equals to zero. Therefore,
$$0 = \int\limits_{-R}^R e^{-x^2}dx + \int\limits_0^y e^{-(R+i\xi)^2}d\xi + \int\limits_R^{-R} e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx + \int\limits_y^0 e^{-(-R+i\xi)^2}d\xi.$$
Now, for second and fourth integrals, we have:
$$\left|\int\limits_0^y e^{-(\pm R + i\xi)^2}d\xi \right|\leq\int\limits_0^y \left| e^{-R^2 \mp 2Ri\xi+\xi^2} \right|d\xi \leq y e^{-R^2+y^2} \rightarrow 0 ~~\text{as} ~~R \rightarrow \infty.$$
Thus, we are getting the needed equality for any real $y$.

But, I don't understand why this is not the end of the proof and why we need part (b). It bothers me because I might not see some important concept about this problem. I would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: The question is asking for *two proofs*.  You've completed the proof for part (a).  Part (b) is asking for an entirely different proof.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you! That is stupid question then.